# Context free grammars with nesting and inequalities

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar, context-free-language

I've been unable to find any examples of context-free grammars that have nesting and inequalities.

For instance, I am trying to write the CFG for:

`{aibjckdl : (i < l) ^ (j < k)}`

So, for `{aidl : (i < l)}`, the CFG would simply be:

`S -> aSd | dS | d`

It would be similar for b and c. But I cannot figure out how to nest the two grammars. Any similar examples or pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion here you have answer to your question :

```
S -> Ad | aSd | Sd
A -> Ac | c | bAc
```

The concept behind this grammar is : First create a part of expression which has a and d satisfying a condition given and then put between a's and d's an expression which is satisfying conditions for b's and c's.